# Flutter animated rotation with relayout

Tags: flutter, animation

I need to rotate a widget with animation and perform relayout.

RotatedBox does just what I want but without animation.

I used TweenAnimationBuilder and Transform.rotate. They do animated rotation, but keep width constraints and don't resize the child.

```dart
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TweenAnimationBuilder<double>(
      tween: Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: pi / 2),
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      builder: (BuildContext context, double angle, Widget? child) {
        return Transform.rotate(
          angle: angle,
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Image.network('https://i.imgur.com/Xl3LjXZ.jpeg'),
              Image.network('https://i.imgur.com/tF3g1JA.jpeg',
                  width: 30, height: 30),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

I can use scale transform but I don't want all the widgets in the child to be scaled.

How can I do animated rotation with child relayout? Thanks.

[Dartpad example](https://dartpad.dev/?id=86c8e1c2626186bc731cdcc41755b40b) (make the result frame narrow like mobile device)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I've found the solution.

I use rotation and scale to make an animation and after animation is finished I change my widget to RotatedBox.

[Dartpad code](https://dartpad.dev/c2fcfd9efd4301bd0cd6c5a80add94a6)